# Possible to programatically access X-Mms-Content-Location?

Tags: android, debugging, mms

I'm seeing a strange issue on a phone and I'm trying to come up with a way to troubleshoot it to find out more.

Is it possible to access the X-Mms-Content-Location attribute of a message from a MMS message programatically, using the Android SDK?

This is one example of the error that I am investigating. If I can access that attribute, then I may be able to code an app which repairs it so the message retrieval succeeds.

```
04-26 19:11:35.573 V/RetrieveTransaction(  299): X-Mms-Content-Location: http://69.78.70..70/servlets/mms?message-id=<GUID_REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>
<snip>
04-26 19:11:35.783 I/InetAddress(  299): Unknown host 69.78.70..70, throwing UnknownHostException 
04-26 19:11:35.793 V/RetrieveTransaction(  299): Unexpected IOException. 
04-26 19:11:35.793 V/RetrieveTransaction(  299): java.io.IOException: Cannot establish route for http://69.78.70..70/servlets/mms?message-id=<GUID_REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>: Unknown host 
04-26 19:11:35.793 V/RetrieveTransaction(  299):  at com.android.mms.transaction.Transaction.ensureRouteToHost(Transaction.java:206) 
04-26 19:11:35.793 V/RetrieveTransaction(  299):  at com.android.mms.transaction.Transaction.getPdu(Transaction.java:171) 
04-26 19:11:35.793 V/RetrieveTransaction(  299):  at com.android.mms.transaction.RetrieveTransaction.run(RetrieveTransaction.java:147) 
04-26 19:11:35.793 V/RetrieveTransaction(  299):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1058) 
04-26 19:11:35.793 E/RetrieveTransaction(  299): Retrieval failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an isolated incident caused by database corruption. The user had used a task-killer on the app and in doing so corrupted the phone's database which stores the MMS information.

A Hard reset took care of the problem. Doing a hard-reset re-creates the filesystem and this particular database